# SpriteKit physicsBody for a line

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I am developing a game with SpriteKit. In my game, the player should be able to draw a line and have things interact with it. I'm using a simple `SKShapeNode` drawn with a `CGMutablePathRef`. However when I add the physicsBody to the line, it automatically reconnects the end of the line to the start. The result is if the user draws a curve, the physicsBody is the shape of a semicircle.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKShapeNode *line = [SKShapeNode node];
        CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, location.x, location.y);
        line.path = pathToDraw;
        [line setStrokeColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [line setLineWidth:5];
        [line setLineCap:kCGLineCapRound];
        [line setLineJoin:kCGLineJoinRound];
        line.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:pathToDraw];
        line.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        line.physicsBody.restitution = 1;
        line.name = @"line";
        [self addChild:line];
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    SKShapeNode *oldLine = (SKShapeNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"line"];
    CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = (CGMutablePathRef)oldLine.path;
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, location.x, location.y);
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"line" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        [node removeFromParent];
    }];

    SKShapeNode *line = [SKShapeNode node];
    line.path = pathToDraw;
    [line setStrokeColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [line setLineWidth:5];
    [line setLineCap:kCGLineCapRound];
    [line setLineJoin:kCGLineJoinRound];
    line.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:pathToDraw];
    line.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    line.physicsBody.restitution = 1;
    line.name = @"line";
    [self addChild:line];
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to prevent the physicsBody path from rejoining back to the beginning. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code draws a temporary line (white) as you move your finger around the screen and then draws a final line (red) when you lift your finger. The code then adds a edge chain physics body to the line.

```
@implementation GameScene {
    SKShapeNode *lineNode;
    CGPoint startingPoint;
}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

    startingPoint = positionInScene;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

    // Remove temporary line if it exist
    [lineNode removeFromParent];

    CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, startingPoint.x, startingPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, positionInScene.x, positionInScene.y);

    lineNode = [SKShapeNode node];
    lineNode.path = pathToDraw;
    lineNode.strokeColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
    lineNode.lineWidth = 1;
    [self addChild:lineNode];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

    // Remove temporary line
    [lineNode removeFromParent];

    CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, startingPoint.x, startingPoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, positionInScene.x, positionInScene.y);

    SKShapeNode *finalLineNode = [SKShapeNode node];
    finalLineNode.path = pathToDraw;
    finalLineNode.strokeColor = [SKColor redColor];
    finalLineNode.lineWidth = 1;

    finalLineNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath:pathToDraw];
    [self addChild:finalLineNode];
}

@end
```

[image]